# Create trigger in Mysql error while adding new row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables model_detail with columns

```
`id``model_id``productName``Color``Available_Quantity`
```

and model_stock with columns

```
`id``model_detail_id``entry_date``amount`
```

model_detail_id is the foreign key pointing to model_detail(**`id`**) table I want to update the **`Available_Quantity`** of model_detail table whenever new 
**`model_stock`** is added and I have tried something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_model_stock AFTER INSERT ON model_stock
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE model_detail
SET Available_Quantity= Available_Quantity + NEW.amount
WHERE model_detail.id = NEW.model_stock.model_detail_id;
END
```

but when I add a row to the **`model_stock`** table I get the error something like this

```
SQL query:
INSERT INTO `model_stock` (`id`, `model_detail_id`, `entry_date`, `amount`) 
VALUES (NULL, '2', '2017-07-11', '20')
```

The error message I received:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>       #1054 - Unknown column 'NEW.model_stock.model_detail_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not add the table name after the `NEW` keword:

```
...
WHERE model_detail.id = NEW.model_detail_id;
...
```